# How to trigger custom workflow action in sitecore with admin login?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

[image]How to trigger custom workflow action in sitecore with admin login? I have created custom class in following way

```
    public class CustomAutoAction
{
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Item dataItem = args.DataItem;
        if (dataItem != null && dataItem.Parent != null) {
            dataItem.Parent ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29261248/4207332) states, actions are executed automatically once you hit Save.

Comment: From what I know Sitecore `adminstrator` accounts always bypass workflows. That's why `administrator` accounts should never be used for content authoring.